# Core data app giving sigabrt error on xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

I have a app which uses core data and it runs properly if i keep it running on xcode on a simulator. And while the app is still running on xcode i press home buton on simulator and then remove the app from multitasking. Untill here there is no problem.

Now if while the app is still running on xcode and if i relaunch my app from simulator the simulator goes black in view but I can access multitasking and nothing else on simulator and xcode shows sigabrt error in main.m file.

If i stop the app on xcode and do the above things i get no error on simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting the stop button in the simulator is the equivalent to what you called "remove the app from multitasking" (AKA, double tap the home button, and then kill the app). Unfortunately, the simulator will throw you an error every time you do that, and then try and launch the app again.. Hitting Stop, then start again is the same thing in simulator, so that's how I would test it.

On a device: Run your app on a device, then hit stop in the simulator. 
Then back on your device, open the app again, and you can test it all day without the annoying error you speak of.

Hope that helps.